# Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec oneOf function has error

Tags: haskell

ghci version is GHCi, version 8.6.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/

```
Prelude> :m +Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
Prelude Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec> oneOf "abcd"

<interactive>:7:1: error:
? Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream s m Char
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    ? When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall s (m :: * -> *) u.
              Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream s m Char =>
              Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m Char
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can not print a `Parser Char` like `oneOf "abcde"`. That would be like printing a function which expects the input text. Functions can not be printed.

(The error is due to parsers involving some extensions you did not turn on, but you can ignore the error you got. That's not the main issue.)

To run a parser, you need to provide a source name and input text as follows:

```
> import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
> parse (oneOf "abcde") "sourceName" "a"
Right 'a'
> parse (oneOf "abcde") "sourceName" "b"
Right 'b'
> parse (oneOf "abcde") "sourceName" "z"
Left "sourceName" (line 1, column 1):
unexpected "z"
```